# Problems with launching packages in anaconda navigator

Tags: anaconda

I have installed packages from anaconda.They were successfully installed,but when I go to home page to launch it, it doesn't show the newly installed package even after I refresh the page. Both the root environment as well as a virtual environment present the same problem.They only show the default packages.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages are launched thru python. If you have installed the packages correcrtly, they are run by placing an import line in you phython code as such

```
import package
```

I don't know where the packages are installed but it's not in your user's directory.